# Inserting and reading image data in sqlite3 iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I have an app, that stores some info about account, including the image. Everything is great: tables are created, data can be saved, but the image is not (I can't understand if the image is not saving or it can't be retrieved from db). My code:

database table:

```
 static const char *accountsTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_accounts (unique_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, provider_id INTEGER, login TEXT, password TEXT, threshold INTEGER, is_need_push INTEGER, comment TEXT, image BLOB)";
```

my insert method:

```
-(BOOL) createAccountWithAccountData:(AccountsData *) accountData
{
    NSInteger pushNotifications = accountData.isNeedPushNotifications ? 1 : 0;
    const char *dbPath = [dataBasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *insertSqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO tbl_accounts (provider_id, login, password, threshold, is_need_push, comment, image) values ('%d', '%@', '%@', '%d', '%d', '%@', '?')", accountData.providerId, accountData.logIn, accountData.password, accountData.threshold, pushNotifications, accountData.comment];

        const char *insertStmt = [insertSqlStatement UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insertStmt, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK ) {
            if (accountData.image != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Image not null");
                NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(accountData.image, 1.0);
                sqlite3_bind_blob(sqlStatement, 7, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], nil);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"image is nil");
            }
            if (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                NSLog(@"Successfully created account data");
                sqlite3_reset(sqlStatement);
                sqlite3_close(database);
                return YES;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Unable to create account data");
                sqlite3_reset(sqlStatement);
                sqlite3_close(database);
                return NO;
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

and my get all accounts method:

```
-(NSArray *) getAllAccounts
{
    const char *dbPath = [dataBasePath UTF8String];
    NSMutableArray *allAccounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"DB Opened");
        NSString *findSqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM tbl_accounts"];
        const char *findStmt = [findSqlStatement UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, findStmt, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"statement was prepared");
            while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSLog(@"Into the while loop");
                NSInteger uniqueId = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 0)] integerValue];
                NSInteger providerId = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 1)] integerValue];
                NSString *logIn = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
                                  (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 2)];
                NSString *password = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
                                   (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 3)];
                NSInteger threshold = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 4)] integerValue];

                NSInteger pushNotif = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 5)] integerValue];

                NSString *comment = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
                                      (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 6)];

                BOOL isNeedNotif = [self convertNSInteger:pushNotif];

                int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlStatement, 7);
                NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(sqlStatement, 7) length:length];

                NSLog(@"itemLogin: %@", logIn);
                NSLog(@"password : %@", password);
                NSLog(@"data is: %@", data);
                NSLog(@"comment is: %@", comment);
                NSLog(@"isNeedNotif: %hhd", isNeedNotif);

                UIImage *imageFromDb = nil;
                if (data != nil)
                    imageFromDb = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                else
                    NSLog(@"No image");

                if (imageFromDb) {
                    NSLog(@"Image");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"NoImage");
                }

                AccountsData *item = [[AccountsData alloc] initWithProviderId:providerId logIn:logIn password:password threshold:threshold isNeedPushNotifications:isNeedNotif comment:comment image:imageFromDb];
                item.unique_id = uniqueId;

                [allAccounts addObject:item];
                NSLog(@"Item added to array");
                NSLog(@"Array count: %d", [allAccounts count]);
            }
        }
        sqlite3_reset(sqlStatement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }

    return allAccounts;
}
```

I've tested it on the emulator and the Image data is (NSDATA, according to NSLog): 
data is: <3f>

Please, help me!!!

Comment: Maybe you should store the image on the device and the path to this image into you database?

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's better, who knows. But the problem is that image can be saved and retrieved, but I wasn't able to do it. That's what I need right know.

Comment: I can't really help so, I always used the method above. I highly suggest you to try it if you can ! :-)

Answer (score 2):

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_accounts (..., image) values (..., '?')
```

You are inserting a string that consists of the single character `?`.

Parameter markers must not be quoted:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_accounts (..., image) values (..., ?)
```

Furthermore, the second parameter of `sqlite3_bind_blob` is the *parameter* number, and the statement has only one parameter; it must be `1`, not `7`.

Additionally, `sqlite3_reset` is necessary only if you want to reuse the statement (but harmless otherwise).
What you must never forget is to call `sqlite3_finalize` when you're done with the statement, and before you close the database.
In this code, just replace `sqlite3_reset` with `sqlite3_finalize`.

Comment: When I do it not quoted, it doesn't put anything into the table. My log says: data is: <>

Comment: Updated for some other bugs. No guarantee that I've found all of them.